# Does weka makes automatic preprocessing with numeric attributes

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Does weka preprocess numeric attributes like speed (meter per second) before the classification?

I want to use the weka toolkit to classify numeric speed and step data . In the related work weka is often used and it is mentioned that the authors of the related work have used mean, standard deviation, max and mean for classification. Does weka do that preprocessing automatically or do I have to do it before classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka doesn't *automatically* do that, but it does have filters for it.  With the [**AddExpression**](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/AddExpression.html) filter, you can compute the mean, standard deviation, max and mean of a number of attributes, just as you described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps a lot! if weka doesn't do a preprocessing and I add attributes with the filter, how can I classify an unlabeled dataset that I want to classify with my newly trained classifier? Do I have to set the filter attributes to unknown?

Comment: You can still compute the new attributes, they don't depend on the labels, right?